# Subscribing to EF changes with RX

Tags: c#, entity-framework, system.reactive

I'm probably totally misunderstanding what RX is all about, but I thought it would be a neat way of allowing various client applications in my code to subscribe to notifications of changes to certain Entity Framework Code First types.

So in my UOW Commit methood I have

```
        var changes = DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<EntEvent>().Where(ee => ee.State != EntityState.Unchanged);
        Hub.Instance.NotifyBeforeSave(changes);
```

and my (rather basic) hub class looks like this...

```
public sealed class Hub
{
    private static readonly Hub instance = new Hub();
    static Hub(){}
    private Hub(){}
    public static Hub Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }

    public IObservable<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry<EntEvent>> BeforeSave = new Subject<DbEntityEntry<EntEvent>>(); 
    public void NotifyBeforeSave<T>(IEnumerable<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry<T>> changes) where T:class
    {
        var  x = changes.Where(c => typeof(T) == typeof(EntEvent)) as IEnumerable<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry<EntEvent>>;
        BeforeSave = x.ToObservable();
    }
}
```

and then I thought I could subscribe a client (observer) by creating an instance of the following and calling attach.

```
public class SampleConsumer : IObserver<DbEntityEntry<EntEvent>>
{
    public void attach()
    {            
        Hub.Instance.BeforeSave.Subscribe(this);
    }

    public void OnNext(DbEntityEntry<EntEvent> value)
    {
        var x = value;
    }

    public void OnError(Exception error)
    {
        var y = error;
    }

    public void OnCompleted()
    {
    }
}
```

but breakpoints in OnNext and OnError never get called.

I'm probably 180deg away from where I should be, but we have to start somewhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have an asynchronous source.

```
DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<EntEvent>()
```

is a collection. You can convert it to an observable using

```
IEnumerble.ToObservable();
```

but that does not make it asynchronous. In fact, it will enumerate the collection right away upon subscription. If the collection happens to be empty, it will do nothing at all. Google the difference between cold/hot observables to understand.
You need an asynchronous source, something like an event.

I don't know EF very well, my guess is that the

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext.SavingChanges
```

event might be what you need.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I'd been reading about hot/cold last night. I guess I was hoping to be able to have a method that, when called, pushed the IEnumerable into as hot events into an Observable. I'm looking at SavingChanges now (your cast was very useful!)

Comment: I guess the problem is that the DBContext is short lived, whereas I need the subscriptions to be long lived, hence the idea of a hub, where consumers can subscribe to a long lived Observable and creators can push events into it. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Plug in Nick's

https://github.com/NickStrupat/EntityFramework.Triggers
https://github.com/NickStrupat/EntityFramework.Rx

He has patterns with and without deriving from his context, that permit:

```
DbObservable<Context>.FromInserted<Person>();
```